# Github and Git GUI

Tags: github

I beginner in SVN and GIT and I have want a GUI git control in Ubuntu, please suggest me.
I description that use of this GUI on Github.

Comment: Out of interest, is there any reason you want to use a GUI for git?  I use SVN professionally every day and git for hobby projects most days, but I find I am faster using git via the terminal than I am with a GUI for SVN, even doing the same tasks.

Comment: gui is simple and fast in work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My prefered git gui is "SmartGit" (http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/) because you can use the "gitflow". Since you've said that your beginner, you should start with learning "gitflow". It will help you afterwards... your coding will be "Agile" ready. Here is a basic course on "gitflow" (http://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/).

Have fun!

Comment: Do you have example with this gui in github ? a compelete example.

Comment: You should read this blog to help you use SmartGit with Gitflow [https://blogs.endjin.com/2015/01/using-smartgit-to-follow-the-gitflow-branching-and-workflow-model/](https://blogs.endjin.com/2015/01/using-smartgit-to-follow-the-gitflow-branching-and-workflow-model/)

Answer (score 1):

Another ting to mention is the `git gui`. This can be started from the terminal: `git gui`

If that didn't work, you may install the `git-all` package:

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install git-all`

and when the installation is complete, run the `git gui` again.

Good luck using git, you may find it confusing in the begining, but it's worth learning and will be usefull for sure!

Comment: how to add github repository (clone) for my project ?